# $(ax)(ay) = a(xy) \in (a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

**Lemma 26.1**
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity element $e$. The set
$(a) = \{ar : r \in R\}$
is an ideal of $R$.

*Proof.*
First, we will show that $(a)$ is a subring of $R.$ Since $a = ae$ then $a ∈ (a)$ and
so $(a) \ne \emptyset$. Let $ax \in (a)$ and $ay \in (a)$. Then $ax − ay = a(x − y) \in (a)$ since
$x − y \in R$. Thus, $ax − ay \in (a).$ Also, $(ax)(ay) = a(xy) \in (a)$ since $xy ∈ R.$
 $(a)$ is a subring of $R$.

> Finally, for any $ar \in (a)$ and all
>       $t ∈ R$ we have $t(ar) = t(ra) = (tr)a \in (a)$ and $(ar)t = a(rt) = (rt)a ∈ (a).$
>       Thus, $(a)$ is an ideal of $R.$

I didn't understand how  $(ax)(ay) = a(xy) \in (a)$ in proof.

Please expain it.

Comment: @AustinMohr, I have fixed this while doing some $\LaTeX$ formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second $a$ appears to be dropped by accident, but the claim is still valid.

Since the ring is commutative, we can write $(ax)(ay) = a(axy)$. Since $a$, $x$, and $y$ all belong to $R$, so does $axy$. Thus, we've writetn $(ax)(ay)$ as "$a$ times a member of $R$", so $(ax)(ay) \in (a)$.

Comment: can you please explain how we proved ideal after proving (a) is subring

Comment: @TLE: The two equalities in the highlighted part of your question show that $(a)$ is closed under left and right, respectively, multiplication by elements of $R$, i.e. that it is a left and right ideal. Actually, only one of them would have sufficed, since when $R$ is a commutative ring, the definitions of left, right, and two-sided ideal coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can safely drop the part of the proof (which contains the step you mention) where you show that if $u, v \in (a)$, then $uv \in (a)$. This is because you are showing next the *stronger* statement that if $u \in (a)$ and $v \in R$, then $u v \in (a)$.

Comment: can you please explain how we proved ideal after proving (a) is subring